# Linux: Do userland threads have a higher priority when performing system calls?

Tags: linux, scheduling, system-calls, priority

From what I understand, Linux features kernel preemption, meaning that a thread executing a system call can be preempted and rescheduled to run on the next epoch.

This leads me to wonder if a thread in a system call has any sort of elevated priority when they get rescheduled.

For example, say I have a userland process with SCHED_OTHER and a priority of 20 (0 is the lowest, 139 is the highest). The process reads an i2c eeprom file from sysfs using the standard read system call. Now when it reads the eeprom, the i2c controller needs to receive each byte one at a time, and so timing is important, we cant wait too long in between receiving bytes otherwise the i2c transaction will timeout.

Now, while receiving bytes from the eeprom the thread gets rescheduled (either it sleeps or gets preempted by a higher priority thread, etc). When the thread gets rescheduled, does it still have the initial low priority of 20? This seems like it would be an issue and it should be treated as higher, since it is interfacing with a device and timing is critical (it seems like I would it expect it to be treated as having a rt priority). I haven't found anything to indicate that threads get a "boosted" priority in these contexts.